# como obtener el valor de un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc, oracle, plsql

tengo una duda estoy usando procedimientos almacenados con oracle y llevarlos a una página web en asp la cuestión es que tengo este procedimiento almacenado del cual obtengo el login y password de la base de datos.

Pero ademas deseo traer una descripción que existe dentro de la misma consulta mi procedimiento esta definido asi como hago para capturar la descripción y llevarlo a un textbox

```
PROCEDURE VALIDARLOGIN (pLOGIN IN VARCHAR2,
                        pPASSWORD IN VARCHAR2,
                        p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN p_cursor FOR
         SELECT USULOGIN, USUPASSW, DESCRIPCION
           FROM SEGMUSUARIO u, DEPENDENCIA d
          WHERE     u.CODIGO = d.CODIGO
                AND (USULOGIN = pLOGIN)
                AND (USUPASSW = pPASSWORD);
   END VALIDARLOGIN;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código de .NET en el que haces la llamada al procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "PKG_LOGIN_FNDREP.VALIDARLOGIN";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("pLOGIN", username);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pPASSWORD", password)

Comment: quiero saber si con el cursor puedo traer el otro parametro del proc almacenado que es descripcion y ponerlo en un text box

Comment: No indicas como recuperas la respuesta del PL, pero voy a suponer que recibes el cursor en un DataTable. Debes hacer dt.Rows[nRow]["DESCRIPCION"].ToString()

Comment: si recibo un cursor y necesito recuperar ese valor lo probare